# Crash Reports not being sent to Apple

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash-reports

I currently have an App that is on the Mac App Store that a couple people have reported instability with. I was able to reproduce the crashes and fix the problem, but what concerned me is that I have no Crash Reports listed for the App in iTunes Connect. When reproducing the crashes myself I did not get the standard crash report dialog asking if I wanted to send the crash report. In Console I do get:

```
6/22/11 9:05:25 AM  ReportCrash[1902]   Saved crash report for Application [1893] version 1.0 (1.0) to /Users/Name/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Application_2011-06-22-090525_MacBook-Pro-4-Lyfe.crash
```

From what I could find on line the crash reporting should be automatic and you should only have to worry about implementing custom crash reporting if you want the reports sent directly to you.

My question is, why are crashes for my App not being sent back in to Apple and then ultimately showing up for me in iTunes Connect? My app is a menu bar item and does not have a full set of menus or dock icon if it matters at all.

Answer (score 4):

Kris,

You do not get all the crash reports on iTunesConnect.

This is how it works:

Lets say you are an iPhone user, when you first activate your iPhone, it asks you if you'd like to send anonymous reports to apple, if you checkmark yes, only then the crash reports from your phone would be sent to apple.
Another thing to keep in mind is, even if a person has checkmarked this option, these reports would be sent, only when the user syncs his iOS device with the iTunes.

So essentially, the answer is

> **You cannot rely on iTunesConnect to get your app's crash
>   reports**

Instead you should use a third party solution, like: Hoptoad:

[airbrakeapp.com](http://airbrakeapp.com/)

I am very sure that there are other solutions like hoptoad as well, but this is what I have used and works very well.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but I'm talking about Mac Apps, not iOS apps so I don't have to rely on the iOS device being sync'd back to iTunes before crash logs can be sent back. For a Mac App it should ask to send the crash report to Apple every time. Crash reports are being generated locally but I don't get the dialog to send to Apple. I understand users not choosing to, but my app isn't even giving them the option. I'd prefer to not have to use a 3rd party solution, specially a paid one.